# What could be the regular expression for the text "192.168.71.1 GET HTTP/1.0 /test/abc"?

Tags: java, regex

what could be the relevant regular expression for the text

> "192.168.71.1 GET HTTP/1.0 /test/abc"

I have tried for regular expressions separately but could not combine all these with a space in betweeen.

Comment: Use `\\s` for a single space in your Java regex.

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: You've forgotten a vital piece of information. Which bits of the string are variable, which bits are you trying to capture? eg: "192.168.71.1", "GET", "/test/abc" etc

Comment: `Pattern.quote("192.168.71.1 GET HTTP/1.0 /test/abc")` is the easiest way to get a regex that matches exactly this text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://regex101.com/ the following works:

`192\.168\.71\.1\sGET\sHTTP\/1\.0\s\/test\/abc`

Remember to escape special characters like `.` and `\` if you want to use them as literals.

> If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex,
>   you need to escape them with a backslash

Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html to see more about **literal** characters and **special** characters.

Of course, if you're trying to match any IP address, a different HTTP version or a different request method, you'll need to specify that in your question so that people can help you more accurately.

There's some good reads on google, take a look at the preview for safari books online at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html which has a few example regular expressions for IP addresses. That should get you started!